# How to iterate through two lists in parallel with one list randomized

Tags: list, python-2.7, iteration, tuples

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python) explained how to iterate through two parallel lists.

When I apply that lesson to a shuffled list, however, I get the following error: "zip argument #2 does not support iteration." Why does a shuffled list not support iteration? How else can I randomize the order of answer choices?

```
import random

def answers():
    answerList = random.shuffle([answer1, answer2, answer3, correct])
    numberList = ["1: ", "2: ", "3: ", "4: "]
    for x,y in zip(numberList,answerList):
        print x,y 

prompt = "What is the average migrating speed of a laden swallow?"
answer1 = "Gas or electric?"
answer2 = "Metric or English?"
answer3 = "Paper or plastic?"
correct = "African or European?"

print prompt
answers()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.shuffle` shuffles *in place*. Do as following:

```
answerList = [answer1, answer2, answer3, correct]
random.shuffle(answerList)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you explain why those two methods produce different results?

Comment: `random.shuffle` returns *None*. And *None* does not support iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pacholik for the solution.

```
import random

def answers():
    answerList = [answer1, answer2, answer3, correct]
    random.shuffle(answerList)
    numberList = ["1: ", "2: ", "3: ", "4: "]
    for x,y in zip(numberList,answerList):
        print x,y 

prompt = "What is the average migrating speed of a laden swallow?"
answer1 = "Gas or electric?"
answer2 = "Metric or English?"
answer3 = "Paper or plastic?"
correct = "African or European?"

print prompt
answers()
```